# Why is the singleton pattern never shown as a class with const constructor?

Tags: dart, singleton

It is a pattern which makes sure we create only one instance of the class.

Most of the time singleton pattern is shown:

```
 class Settings {
      static final Settings _instance = Settings._internal();
      factory Settings() {
        return _instance;
      }
      Settings._internal() {}
    }
```

disadvantages: difficult to test and violates single responsibility

What about:

```
class Singleton{
   const Singleton();
}


Singleton s1=  const Singleton();
Singleton s2=  const Singleton();

  void main() {
    print(s1==s2); //true
}
```

Easy to test.  Only one 1 responsibility of the object.

My question is why people make life more difficult and never implement Singleton with const constructor. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Because a singleton like the one you show is pretty useless. You can't change any of the fields. Why would you need a "singleton" in the first place?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the purpose of a const singleton like the one you show? Maybe how it could replace what most people use singleton's for?

Comment: To create a compile-time constant using a constant constructor, put the const keyword before the constructor name.Constructing two identical compile-time constants results in a single, canonical instance

Comment: Yes that's the whole purpose of `const`. AFAIK, no one tries to use the singleton pattern for constants.

Comment: People use the singleton pattern as a method of obtaining a handle that gives access to the same data across different scopes in an application. You show a singleton implementation with no fields, which would be just as useful as a `const` constructor as you propose. But most people don't use a singleton with no non-final field so it cannot be considered an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Christopher Moore's comments about a `const`, immutable singleton being unlikely to be useful, a non-`factory` `const` constructor does not guarantee a single instance, which would violate the singleton pattern.  Callers would need to *explicitly* invoke the constructor in a `const` context:

```dart
class Foo {
  const Foo();
}

void main() async {
  const foo1 = Foo();
  const foo2 = Foo();
  var foo3 = Foo();

  print(foo1 == foo2); // Prints: true
  print(foo1 == foo3); // Prints: false
}
```

In contrast, a `factory` constructor can guarantee that only a single instance is created with no additional burden on the callers.